# Connection string to MS-Access database stored in Azure file storage

Tags: azure, ms-access, connection-string

While converting a legacy desktop application to a web application I have a requirement for importing MS-Access databases (.mdb files) to the new application.

Currently the database is uploaded to Azure file storage through the website, and a notification is added to an Azure queue. Then my import service (prompted by the Azure queue) will read the MS-Access database content and import it to my AzureSQL database. The file storage does NOT have public access.

The issue I am facing is that my import service currently has to download the MS-Access database from Azure file storage in order to connect to it. If possible, I would like to avoid the download.

My question is: Is it possible for my import service to connect to the MS-Access database (.mdb) while it is in Azure file storage? What would the connection string look like?

Comment: How is your application deployed in Azure? Is it deployed as WebApp, Cloud Service or Virtual Machine? Also, when you say `Azure File Storage` do you mean `Azure File Storage` (which supports SMB protocol) or do you mean `Azure Blob Storage`?

Comment: The application is deployed as a WebApp, which does not include drivers for connecting to MS-Access. By Azure File Storage I mean the Azure File Storage - it is my understanding that Azure Blob Storage does not support database connections at all.

Comment: @ThomasJørgensen I am struggling with similar issue. Can you please explain: 1. How your import service running as a WebApp opens MS Access database if there is no driver available? 2. Is import service a continuous WebJob triggered by queue message?

Comment: The application that uploads the Access database is deployed as a WebApp. But the import service needs to be deployed somewhere else, in an environment where you can add an Access driver. In my case it is a scheduled task on a virtual machine. WebJobs are part of a WebApp, so they do not have the Access driver, and cannot get it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it by mounting the Azure File Storage as a drive, and then treat it as I would any MS-Access database file in the local file system.